# Boot Yielding no results in R -> Error in coding

Tags: r

I have tried various ways to conduct the bootstrapping of daily return data from equities. I have created a strategy which is based on an oscillator (RSI) and the log return of the corresponding security. Somehow however I am unable to sucessfully bootstrap with this code, I only receive zeros for t1, bias and std error and :

```
bs <- function(myfunction,data, indices) 

{
  data_log_stock     <- data[indices,1]

  data_RSI_stock_new <- data[indices,2]

  fit <- myfunction(data_RSI_stock_new,30,70,data_log_stock)

  my_output <- tradeStats(fit,"Mean")

  return(my_output) 
} 

boot_result <- boot(data = cbind(log_stock, RSI_stock), statistic=bs, R=100)

boot_result
```

Can anyone spot the mistake I am making?

Comment: remove the myfunction parameter.

Comment: still doesnt work :(

Comment: Sorry, can't help you without a reproducible example.